# Compare First 3 Character String with List of String of Each String First 3 Character

Tags: java

The Sample Code which needs a solution?

```
public class TestJJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String abc="123XXXXX0";

        ArrayList<String> lstValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        lstValues.add("111XXXX1");
        lstValues.add("122XXX1");
        lstValues.add("123XXXX1");
        if(lstValues.subList(0, 3).contains(abc.substring(0, 3))){
            System.out.println("**** Match Found ***");
        }else{
            System.out.println("**** No Match Found ****");
        }

    }

}
```

Which should return match found but its returning no match found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't currently comparing the first three characters because `subList` doesn't actually apply a substring function (here it copies the list as is). You can also initialize your `List` more efficiently (and you should program to the `List` interface). I would `stream()` it and `map` each element using `String.substring` and `anyMatch`. Like,

```
String abc = "123XXXXX0";
List<String> lstValues = new ArrayList<>(List.of("111XXXX1", "122XXX1", "123XXXX1"));
if (lstValues.stream().map(x -> x.substring(0, 3)).anyMatch(abc.substring(0, 3)::equals)) {
    System.out.println("**** Match Found ***");
} else {
    System.out.println("**** No Match Found ****");
}
```

Which outputs

```
**** Match Found ***
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , In my project we are using 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the full `String` in the list but rather a substring of one of strings in the list.

You will have to loop through the list and check with each `String` individually.

```
String temp = abc.substring(0,3);
boolean flag = true;
for(String value: lstValues.subList(0, 3))
 if(value.contains(temp)) // or if(value.indexOf(temp) != -1)
  {
    System.out.println("**** Match Found ****");
    flag = false;
    break;
  }
if(flag)
  System.out.println("**** No Match Found ****");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are supposed to do.

```
String first3 = abc.substring(0,3);
boolean found = false;
for (String s : lstValues) {
    if (s.startsWith(first3)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (found) {
    System.out.println("**** Match Found ***");
} else {
    System.out.println("**** No Match Found ****");
}
```

Go through the list checking each entry until you find a match.

Answer (score 0):

List.contain(Object o)  checks if the "object"  is in the list or not . In your case the objects those are in the List is String and they are "111XXXX1" , "122XXX1"  and "122XXX1" . So if the following will return true only

`lstValues.contain("111XXXX1")`--> true 
`lstValues.contain("122XXX1")` --> true 
`lstValues.contain("122XXX1")` --> true

But if you do the following it will return false :

lstValues.contain("123") --> false .

Here is what javadoc says for List.contains(Object o)

Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

So you can see it determines if the object is equal or not . So none of the  items in the ArrayList matches to "123" . Therefore you will get a "No Match Found"

Answer (score 0):

java 1.7

try this ..

```
`public static void main(String[] args) {

    String abc = "123XXXXX0";

    ArrayList<String> lstValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    lstValues.add("111XXXX1");
    lstValues.add("122XXX1");
    lstValues.add("123XXXX1");

    boolean found = false;

    for (String temp : lstValues.subList(0, 3)) {
        if (temp.contains(abc.substring(0, 3))) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        System.out.println("**** Match Found ***");
    } else {
        System.out.println("**** No Match Found ****");
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thanks ! I need the reverse condition also to be verified , Assume the list contains 123 it should not set value for found to be true.

Comment: What exact you want to achieve , can u please elaborate or can u please write the expected output ?

Comment: String abc = "123XXXXX0" , Value 123 if present in ArrayList <"123","111","122"> and if i add !temp.contains(abc.substring(0, 3)) it should not enter if block , but it iteraters atleast once.