# Compare Substring value with ArrayList String of Substring

Tags: java

Need solution for the sample code posted below,

```
public class TestJJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String abc="123XXXXX0";

        ArrayList<String> lstValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        lstValues.add("111XXXX1");
        lstValues.add("122XXX1");
        lstValues.add("123XXXX1");
        if(!(abc.substring(0, 3).matches(lstValues.subList(0,3)))){
            System.out.println("**** Match Found ***");
        }else{
            System.out.println("**** No Match Found ****");
        }

    }

}
```

which should display No Match found , I am working on java 1.7.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. Have you at least read the compilation error, tried to understand it and tried a fix? What is the code **supposed** to do?

Comment: Not sure how to compare with the list of string

Comment: You can't compare a String with a List. That's like comparing a banana with a car. What is the code **supposed** to do? If you could tell it in English, you could probably tell it with code, too.

Comment: just take the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54049373/10671804 and use a for loop instead of a stream.

Comment: You have already asked this question once and even accepted an answer, why are you asking again? This question should be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String abc="123XXXXX0";

    ArrayList<String> lstValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    lstValues.add("111XXXX1");
    lstValues.add("122XXX1");
    lstValues.add("123XXXX1");

      for (int i=0;i<lstValues.size();i++){
          String value=lstValues.get(i);
          if(value.substring(0,3).equals(abc.substring(0,3))){
             System.out.println("Found");
          }
          else {
           System.out.println("Not Found");   
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop each values of list and compare it with your String like below,

```
public class TestJJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String abc = "123XXXXX0";

        ArrayList<String> lstValues = new ArrayList<>();
        lstValues.add("111XXXX1");
        lstValues.add("122XXX1");
        lstValues.add("123XXXX1");

        String message = "**** No Match Found ****";

        for (String value : lstValues) {
            if (abc.substring(0, 3).matches(value.substring(0, 3))) {
                message = "**** Match Found ***";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(message);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for loop for that, As follows

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String abc="123XXXXX0";

    ArrayList<String> lstValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    lstValues.add("111XXXX1");
    lstValues.add("122XXX1");
    lstValues.add("123XXXX1");
    int count = 0;
    for(String s:lstValues)
    {
        if(abc.substring(0, 3).matches(s.substring(0,3))){
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0){
        System.out.println("Match Found");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No Match Found");
    }
}
```